# Convergence of $\chi\left\{ u_{\varepsilon}>0\right\}$ when $u_\varepsilon$ is the standard mollification of $u\in L^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Assume that $u\in L^{p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset R^n$  is bounded, and that $u_{\varepsilon}$ is the
standard mollification. Does this imply that

$$
\chi\left\{ x\in\Omega:u_{\varepsilon}(x)>0\right\} \rightarrow\chi\left\{ x\in\Omega:u(x)>0\right\} \text{ in }L^{p}_{loc}(\Omega),
$$

where $\chi$ is the charasteristic function?

Answer (score 0):

By boundedness of $\Omega$, we may apply the dominated convergence theorem to the a.e. convergence
$$
\chi_{\left\{ x\in\Omega:u_{\varepsilon}(x)>0\right\}} \rightarrow \chi_{\left\{ x\in\Omega:u(x)>0\right\}}, ~~~~\epsilon \to 0
$$
which comes from the fact that
$$
\operatorname{ess sup} u_\epsilon \subseteq \operatorname{ess sup} u + B_\epsilon(0)
$$
and the a.e. convergence $u_\epsilon \to u$; to prove this convergence, we pick a sequence of simple functions $s_n \to u$ (a.e. convergence) so that the convergences $s_n^- \to u^-$ and $s_n^+ \to u^+$ are monotone (so that we also obtain $L^p$ convergence by the monotone convergence theorem) and apply the triangle inequality twice, first choosing $n$ and then $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm not sure how to get the a.e. convergence of the characteristic functions. What if, for example, $u=0$ and $u_\epsilon=\epsilon$. Then $u_\epsilon \rightarrow  u$ a.e., but  $\chi\left\{ x\in\Omega:u_{\varepsilon}(x)>0\right\} = 1$ and $\chi\left\{ x\in\Omega:u_{\varepsilon}(x)>0\right\}  = 0$. Of course this does not happen if $u_\epsilon$ is defined by the standard convolution as then also $u_\epsilon$=0.